# how to call a Python function with arguments from Kotlin(or Java) using Chaquopy

Tags: python, java, android, kotlin, chaquopy

I'm trying to figure out chaquopy and understand how to call a function without arguments, but for my application I need to call a function with a String argument taken from EditText. How can I write this?

```
val py: Python = Python.getInstance()
     val pyObj: PyObject = py.getModule("script")


     CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
         for (i in 1..1000000) {
             val integral: PyObject = pyObj.callAttr("main",function.toString() )
             setLatex(sText, integral.toString())
             delay(200)
         }
```

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *
def main(function):

   return sym.latex(function)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain what `function` is, but if it's an `EditText`, then you should instead write `function.getText().toString()`.

If that isn't the problem, please edit the question to explain what went wrong, including any error message, and post a comment below this answer to notify me. If your app crashed, you can find the stack trace by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173).